# Install ISO boots but then freezes

Tags: installation, boot, disk

I've downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 and put it on a usb stick using unetbootin. I successfully booted the USB, Ubuntu starts and I see the classic Ubutnu splash screen. Then the computer freezes. Disk is not reading (as far as I can say from the disk icon), nothing is happening. Next time I did this I pressed `ESC` to see some output:

[image]

I was wondering, maybe the disk has some problems so I tried to use "check the disk for defects", but no errors found.

I've tried to burn the ISO file to a CD - the same. The md5 verifies the ISO file is ok. I've even tried Linux Mint and I experienced exactly same problem with slighly different text messages.

Two notes: I've had dualboot with Windows and those are still working properly, so I don't think this is hardware issue. I have a ext4 partition on the disk - could that interfere somehow? I can format it, but I am lazy to do that unless necessary.

Dell latitude e5410.

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say how much we can concider this as an answer, but it is a solution. I've decided to give a try to 32bit installation ISO, which worked. Unfortunately I can't tell why, because I have no idea what so ever. I installed the system and everything works fine. When I tried later on (after the install) the 64bit ISO again, I was able to load it. I have no idea why as well.

Anyway, if you experience any trouble similiar to this, just try to use 32bit installation ISO.